# tensorflow argmax returns tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, tensorflow-serving

I' trying to construct neural network in tensorflow with `tf.contrib.estimator`
but

```
 logits = tf.reduce_mean(conv2, axis=[1, 2])

    y = tf.argmax(logits, axis=1),
    # If prediction mode, early return
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, predictions=y)

    loss_op = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=y_onehot, logits=logits)
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss_op, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())

    # Add evaluation metrics (for EVAL mode)
    acc_op = tf.contrib.metrics.accuracy(labels=y_, predictions=tf.cast(y, tf.uint8))
```

returns an error:

```
 raise TypeError('{} must be Tensor, given: {}'.format(tensor_name, x)) TypeError: predictions must be Tensor, given: (<tf.Tensor  'ArgMax:0' shape=(10,) dtype=int64>,)
```

Comment: What is the shape of `conv2` ?

Comment: What did you expect to get after `argmax` ?

Comment: conv2 shape is (10, 360, 640, 2)

Comment: @Sunreef , after argmax i expect Tensor with shape (10,) not the tuple with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in comma at the ending

```
y = tf.argmax(logits, axis=1),
```